# Baixar arquivo PDF por link no e-mail

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Desenvolvi uma função que passando o id do Item ele gera um arquivo PDF.

```
[HttpPut]
public void GerarPDF(long idItem)
{
....Função
}
```

Ela já funciona perfeitamente, fiz o teste através do app do Google Chrome chamado PostMan, e passando o caminho ele gera o PDF e baixa tudo certinho, porém se eu enviar este mesmo caminho no corpo de um e-mail através de um `<a></a>` para que a pessoa que recebeu o email possa gerar o PDF, este caminho não funciona:

```
"<a href=http://localhost:11599/Item/GerarPDF?idItem=" + IdItem.ToString() + "> link Download PDF </a>"
```

Dando o seguinte erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora não sei se é pelo fato de estar tentando abrir por localhost ou não, se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço.

Comment: Ja tentou hospedar em algum outro endereço sem ser o localhost pra ver se funciona?

Comment: Vou fazer isso, acredito que seja devido ao localhost mesmo.

Comment: Seu sistema está hospedado ou está somente em localhost? No seu computador o e-mail funciona? Retire o `[HttpPut]` ou altere para `[HttpGet]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu utilizo assim para fazer o Download.

```
public FileResult DownloadAnexo(int id)
{
    string URL = //BUSCAR URL ARQUIVO DESEJADO;
    return File(URL, "multipart/mixed", "Nome_SeuArquivo");
}
```

Observe que o retorno é um **`FileResult`**

Comment: Obrigado amigos, fiz uma combinação com as dicas de vocês e funcionou.

Answer (score 5):

Uma âncora (`<a href ...>`) **sempre vai mandar um GET** pro servidor.

Este é o problema, a *action* está respondendo requisições **PUT** e não **GET**.

Só mudar o atributo de `[HttpPut]` para `[HttpGet]` já vai fazer com que a action seja chamada.

```
[HttpGet]
public void GerarPDF(long idItem)
{
}
```